# How accurate and reliable is GeolocationCoordinates.speed API?

Tags: javascript, web, geolocation, gps

I was wondering how accurate and reliable is the property `speed` of a single sample of `GeolocationCoordinates` API.

I want to take few samples of the current speed of an object (with GPS) and I am not sure if I should calculate the velocity myself (by the distance traveled between two time samples using `altitude`, `longitude` and `altitude`), or just use the property `speed` of a simple `GeolocationCoordinates` sample.

How does the `speed` property is being measured?
Which approach should I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The **GeolocationCoordinates.speed** read-only property is a double
> representing the **velocity** of the device in meters per second.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationCoordinates/speed), also [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation/#speed-attribute) might help

So I guess you don't have to calculate it manually.

**TIP:** For better accuracy, make sure the device is not in battery save mode, as it affects the result a lot.